# loadResourceasStream from a subfolder of the project java

Tags: java

I am sure it's a basic  question , I just can't figure it out
I am trying to load  bunch of images  located in  images subfolder of my project

here is my code

```
package com.ieml.swt.diploma;

import java.io.InputStream;



public class loadTest
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

System.out.println(getResourceImage("marks.png"));
    }


    public static InputStream getResourceImage(String fileName) {

        return loadTest.class.getResourceAsStream("./images/" + fileName);
    }
}
```

I have a separe folders for src and class files
so .java file is located in  src/com/ieml/swt/diploma folder
and .class file under bin/com/ieml/swt/diploma folder
files I'm trying to load  here  do existt in the "loadTest/images" subfolder loadTest is my project's root directory
it justs print s null like it's doesn't load this file
am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
loadTest.class.getResourceAsStream("./images/" + fileName);
```

This will look for the images under `bin/com/ieml/swt/diploma/images`, i.e. relative to the `.class` file. If you leave out the dot in the beginning, it will look in `bin/images`.

But whatever you do, `Class.getResourceAsStream()` is for loading resources *from the classpath*, i.e. inside the `bin` folder. There is no way to access anything outside, and it wouldn't make much sense anyway, since it's designed to work for JAR files as well. Usually, you actually put the resources in the `src` folder and copy them to `bin` during the build (eclipse will do this automatically).

Comment: ye I had the copying idea on my mind in this situatiation it would be no problem, but what if my files a large like 5-10 MB in size each?. that's why I decided to put them in a separate folder rather then in bin. so i tried both loadTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./images/" + fileName); and loadTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/" + fileName); with no luck could you please explain where does it trying look up the file in the last 2 cases ?

Comment: @usmazat: in both cases it will look in bin/images. As I said: getResourceAsStream() *cannot* go outside the classpath, no matter what you do. Copying a few 10 MB files is not that much of a problem, especially since you shouldn't need to do a full build very often with a good IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The `getResourceAsStream()` method loads classpath resources. Make sure that the images directory in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Class.getResourceAsStream will take paths relative to the location of the class file, in your case the classes/com/ieml/swt/diploma folder. You may want to try

```
  loadTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../images/" + filename);
```

I assume that your images folder is on the same level as your bin or classes folder. The basic idea is that you can get a resource by a relative path from your classloader root (your classpath root).

This is not always a good idea but since this looks like a school project I don't think that would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, this may not be the right way to go about it.  getResourceAsStream is commonly used to load icons from a jar on the classpath.  If you're just trying to get a hold of an image on disk for some reason, take a look at the static methods on javax.imageio.ImageIO: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/